# Discord.py text to assign role

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am already building a discord.py bot. However, I want to make it assign roles without the use of prefix in a specific channel - I mean in **#roles** channel. If a member writes **"Mage"**, and if Mage role is already created, bot will assign the role to member. I looked for a reaction role but I need something more specific. I am waiting for your ideas and help. Have a great day!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This isn't a free service where we write a code for you. You have to try yourself and show us what you've done, and we can help along the way. Have a read on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question! For your question itself, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63683599/14196628) can guide you a bit

Comment: I am sorry for ask write code for me. I know its being lazy but I tried a lot and search couldn't find it. I keep in mind for next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message): # Using on_message event reference you dont need to have a prefix
    guild = message.author.guild
    if message.content.lower() == "what the message name should be":  # Checks if the WHOLE message is that one word, so not if that one word was part of a message
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="role name") # Gets the role
        if role is not None: # makes sure role exists
            await message.author.add_roles(role) # Assigns role to the message author
```